# (ASP.NET MVC) this.Model stays emply after loading with IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So my ASP.NET teacher showed us his Sorting function for a table and it honestly seems pretty messed-up or he can't explain it correctly to us.

So in his **Controller** he adds a sort function and changes the index one to theses:

```
 public ActionResult Sort(string by)
    {
        if (by == (string)Session["UserSortBy"])
            Session["UserSortAscendant"] = !(bool)Session["UserSortAscendant"];
        else
            Session["UserSortAscendant"] = true;

        Session["UserSortBy"] = by;
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        if (Session["UserSortBy"] == null)
        {
            Session["UserSortBy"] = "Name";
            Session["UserSortAscendant"] = true;
        }

        List<UserItemView> users = null;
        User sessionUser = OnlineUsers.GetSessionUser();
        switch ((string)Session["UserSortBy"])
        {
            case "FirstName":
                if ((bool)Session["UserSortAscendant"])
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderBy(b => b.FirstName).ToList();
                else
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderByDescending(b => b.FirstName).ToList();
                break;
            case "LastName":
                if ((bool)Session["UserSortAscendant"])
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderBy(b => b.LastName).ToList();
                else
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderByDescending(b => b.LastName).ToList();
                break;
            case "BirthDate":
                if ((bool)Session["UserSortAscendant"])
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderBy(b => b.BirthDate).ToList();
                else
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderByDescending(b => b.BirthDate).ToList();
                break;
            case "CreationDate":
                if ((bool)Session["UserSortAscendant"])
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderBy(b => b.CreationDate).ToList();
                else
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderByDescending(b => b.CreationDate).ToList();
                break;
            case "Sex":
                if ((bool)Session["UserSortAscendant"])
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderBy(b => b.Sex).ToList();
                else
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderByDescending(b => b.Sex).ToList();
                break;
            case "Email":
                if ((bool)Session["UserSortAscendant"])
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderBy(b => b.Email).ToList();
                else
                    users = DB.Users.UserList(sessionUser).OrderByDescending(b => b.Email).ToList();
                break;
        }

        return View(users);
    }
```

Then he makes a new **model** for user that simply branch off the main one (I feel like this is redundant):

```
public class UserItemView
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
    public SexType Sex { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public bool Admin { get; set; }
    public UserItemView() { }

    public UserItemView(User user)
    {
        Id = user.Id;
        UserName = user.UserName;
        FirstName = user.FirstName;
        LastName = user.LastName;
        BirthDate = user.BirthDate;
        CreationDate = user.CreationDate;
        Sex = user.Sex;
        Email = user.Email;
        Admin = user.Admin;
    }
}
```

But then upon execution the **Model** of the page stays null:
 [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP9zP.png)

Anyone knows or has an idea of what did I clearly not understood?

Comment: The code in the `Sort` method may work but it is not readable. The code in there is simply "Showing off". The new model which is created is because your domain model is not adequate for the view so another class is created. This is pretty normal and someone, somewhere called it a "View Model" and the rest of the people jumped on the band wagon: So if you want to know more, search for "What is a view model in MVC". I also do not understand why it is called "Ascendant" when the actual term is "Ascending".

Comment: Session variable was set using `Session["UserSortBy"] = "Name"`. `Name` does not match any of the switch keys so `users` will remain `null`

Comment: Change `List<UserItemView> users = null;` to `List<UserItemView> users = new List<UserItemView>;` (and hopefully you will get a new teacher soon)

Comment: Yeah hes one of the main teachers of the program, yet every student makes jokes about him. He even has a sub-reddit dedicated to his shitty examples. Thanks ill go try that.